# Making MCMC algorithm from R's FME package converge around optimised parameter values in non-linear DDE model

Tags: r, ode, model-fitting, desolve

I have the following non-linear DDE (delay differential equation) model solved with deSolve:

```
    model <- function(parms, times = seq(0, 60, 1)) {
}
```

The known parameters are:

```
G <- structure(c(-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
         0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 
         0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1), dim = c(8L, 22L))

U <- structure(c(9.6, 0, 0, 1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 11.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01), dim = c(22L, 8L))

forcing_func <- approxfun(x = c(0:60),
          y = c(3.789978749,5.316037452,5.185396143,6.558284554,5.549130548,5.712633241,
                4.152581514,5.942285729,5.814900551,3.968558097,4.276266213,5.616072402,
                6.407433514,1.79539372,0.633871866,5.303194797,4.099478638,4.137054321,
                4.175807584,1.877168312,1.93214366,0.393710033,2.64911332,4.674492235,
                3.698606684,3.442866381,3.73217674,4.638280031,3.754229767,2.865937731,
                1.459804928,2.069766183,1.808161085,3.305388336,3.092063238,3.593206788,
                3.8777349,2.819175366,3.55283987,4.51495667,2.009203206,2.304827672,
                3.109626536,4.471240675,4.004597144,4.4204254,4.381900771,2.069175771,
                -1.341448145,4.540838287,3.310323684,2.70840268,2.807892132,3.090647561,
                3.077577537,2.805257996,3.38624182,3.286864016,2.591419861,-3.114741981,
                5.874225293)/100)
```

The starting parameter values are (based on visual comparison between data and outputs):

```
    parms <- list(
  G = G,
  U = U,
  alpha_9 = 0.045,
  alpha_11 = 1.8,
  gamma = 1/3,
  tau_1 = 8,
  tau_2 = 2,
  z_e = 0.75,
  c = 2,
  i = 3,
  k_1 = 0.5,
  k_2 = 0.6,
  n = 0.1,
  q = 0.02,
  delta = 0.2)
```

This is my data:

```
data <- structure(list(label = c("u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", "u1", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", 
"u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u3", "u4", "u4", "u4", "u4", "u4", "u4", 
"u4", "u4", "u4", "u4", "u4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", 
"s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s8", "s8", "s8", "s8", "s8", "s8", 
"s8", "s8", "s8", "s8", "s8"), time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
0, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 0, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 
29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 0, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49), 
    value = c(3.24406229750676, 3.24529921770188, 3.30999392307195, 
    4.90064495158511, 6.47113483169738, 7.39318318121391, 5.43023912454796, 
    5.99536558710986, 6.72344971662373, 6.09831566465937, 4.42937629378807, 
    3.97134606875211, 5.78036541991601, 5.4689247746114, 2.95374636834702, 
    3.31021629913642, 2.86113772997592, 2.5675164398153, 3.34789915159254, 
    3.34551666519448, 2.66765839921454, 2.33677898884761, 2.58119782921292, 
    2.28347874367683, 2.37466930175288, 2.0011187459536, 2.36939791414476, 
    3.24749629574441, 3.5769155243051, 3.21823760580411, 2.85565628815629, 
    2.73520083932854, 2.21677481653148, 2.75677120669056, 3.19434802321364, 
    2.54418699186992, 2.65048506014746, 2.01223641524736, 1.95144023986766, 
    2.27822759631491, 2.06042863359443, 2.06007595772787, 2.23510657453936, 
    3.37162931372549, 4.19484198023565, 7.47734649610678, 7.46145283018868, 
    6.76642007133593, 5.33651666666667, 7.53477958333333, 7.95332207207207, 
    7.22536031108826, 6.68377436416087, 6.34325092421442, 5.62865849506299, 
    5.17861436170213, 6.34115107913669, 6.40804546941446, 6.04034673366834, 
    6.30620105549881, 8.51649908592322, 3.979, 4.11, 4.179, 4.331, 
    4.531, 4.51, 4.755, 4.891, 5.568, 5.671, 5.958, 6.391, 6.58, 
    6.758, 6.841, 6.937, 6.937, 7.143, 7.206, 7.064, 7.327, 7.552, 
    7.669, 7.72, 7.819, 8.079, 8.397, 8.575, 9.163, 9.061, 8.921, 
    9.376, 9.381, 9.906, 9.906, 10.903, 11.34, 12.046, 12.562, 
    12.989, 13.532, 13.358, 13.419, 14.12, 14.682, 14.75, 15.218, 
    15.288, 15.631, 16.1, 16.295, 16.711, 18.272, 18.488, 19.133, 
    20.356, 20.238, 20.626, 20.552, 20.576, 2.3, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 
    4.75, 4.5, 5.1, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8.75, 75, 90, 100, 125, 150, 
    175, 200, 225, 275, 300, 350, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 70, 75, 
    90, 100, 125, 140)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "510", "1010", "151", "201", "251", 
"301", "351", "401", "451", "501", "123", "511", "1011", "152", 
"202", "252", "302", "352", "402", "452", "502", "124", "512", 
"1012", "153", "203", "253", "303", "353", "403", "453", "503"
))
```

Now, I have tried to fit some parameters based on the available data using the adaptive and delayed rejection MCMC algorithm from the FME package. However, I cannot seem to get it to converge:

```
    Objective <- function(x, parset = names(x)) {
  parms[parset] <- x
  out <- model(parms) #,tout
  ## Model cost
  return(modCost(obs = data, model = out, y = "value")) 
}

Fit <- modMCMC(f = Objective,
               p = c(alpha_9 = 0.045,
                     alpha_11 = 1.8, 
                     z_e = 0.75,   
                     c = 2,       
                     i = 3,     
                     k_1 = 0.5,     
                     k_2 = 0.6,      
                     n = 0.1,     
                     q = 0.02,   
                     delta = 0.2),
               lower = c(0.01,    
                         0.01,     
                         0.01,     
                         0.1,    
                         0.1,    
                         0.1,     
                         0.1,      
                         0.01,    
                         0.001,  
                         0),     
               upper = c(1,       
                         10,     
                         1,       
                         10,      
                         10,    
                         1,       
                         1,      
                         3,     
                         10,   
                         10),  
               niter = 2000,
               updatecov = 100,
               ntrydr = 2)
```

How can the routine be modified to make it converge?

Comment: Before running MCMC it is often a good idea to analyze identifiability of the parameters and to try parametric model fitting to get reasonable estimates. Then it is a good idea to start MCMC with a subset of identifiable parameters first. Finally, it may be considered if and how constraints can be avoided.

Comment: @tpetzoldt The constraints are not needed, I have only added them thinking it might aid the algorithm. If the formal model fitting does not seem to work, is there a way to anyways get the MCMC algorithm to converge around a minimum for my model?

Comment: Yes, there is a way: you can use informative priors. Otherwise, you need to experiment with your model, e.g. by an identifiability analysis or by doing parametric model fits or MCMC with subsets of parameters. Brute force has only limited value in such cases.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I've tried with subsets of parameters suggested by identifiability analysis and I have added weight = "mean" in modCost, but I keep getting the following error: 
Error in approx(xMod, yMod, xout = xDat) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
Calls: modMCMC -> logP -> logP_type5 -> f -> modCost -> approx
Could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: It means that in function `modCost` less than 2 valid data were available for an interpolation. It's impossible to say more without a specific reproducible example.